# What happened to EDP445?

Tags: american-football, media

What happened to sports youtuber edp445? He had a channel with 2M+ subscribers but [his channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjicDRtQRDZdgQzYAettQhg) has been terminated. Why was his channel terminated?

Comment: **Moderator note**: as this issue involves a potential ongoing criminal investigation, please keep all interactions on this question to verifiable facts. Any speculation will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[EDP445 has been accused of paedophilia](https://www.insider.com/edp-bryant-moreland-edp445-youtuber-accused-messaging-young-girl-2021-4) and has deleted all the videos from his channel.